# How to bulk identify mixed content errors in blogger

Tags: https, blogger

I'm looking for a way to easily check 1000's of blog posts in blogger for mixed content errors.

I've found some crawling tools, but they are limited to the number of posts they will do or they get blocked by blogger for crawling too fast.

I've got an export that I can search. Is just looking for "http:" going to be enough?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: For checking, directly searching `http://` in the exported XML file should be a good approach. This will be able to identify errors in post content. Also, as most of the errors are caused by images (which can normally be served via HTTPS if hosted on Blogger), you can also try adding - `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` to resolve them - https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/csp-upgrade-insecure-requests/